# allow user to login from both userename or email

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my site I want to allow users to login from both email or username. I tried following but it is login only when I go with Email not with username

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(username.Text) & !string.IsNullOrEmpty(password.Text)) {
    string str = "select * from login where username=@username or email = @email and Password=@password";
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(str, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", username.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password.Text);
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    da.Fill(ds);
    con.Close();
    user = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("username");
    email = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("email");
    pswd = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("password");
    page = ds.Tables(0).Rows(0)("link");
    if (ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > 0) {
        if (user == username.Text.ToString | email == username.Text.ToString & pswd == password.Text.ToString) {
            Response.Cookies("User_Type").Value = "manager";
            Response.Cookies("masterLogin").Value = username.Text;
            Response.Redirect(page);
        } else {
            Response.Write("<script language='javascript'>alert('User name or password is invalid');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you storing plain-text passwords? Don't do that.

Comment: Why not use [asp.net authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eeyk640h.aspx). It takes care of password encryption, user lock out and much, much more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This Answer Just try to replace your code with following code

```js
    if (user == username.Text.ToString || email == username.Text.ToString 
        && pswd == password.Text.ToString) {
```

Answer (score 1):

use the below sql query.

```
select * from login where (username=@username or email = @email) and [Password]=@password // Password is a reserved keyword you cant use this as a column name.
```

and please specify what error exactly you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is in this line:

```
if (user == username.Text.ToString | email == username.Text.ToString 
    & pswd == password.Text.ToString) {
```

Instead of `|` and `&`, you need to write `||` and `&&`.

Also, you should put the `||` into brackets, because `&&` has higher precedence.

So this is the solution:

```
if ((user == username.Text.ToString || email == username.Text.ToString) 
    && pswd == password.Text.ToString) {
```

Comment: I debugged my code & I don't see any error on this line. My query generating empty results which creating problem

Comment: @SUN The usage of single | and & is in general wrong. These are bit operators. You should always use the boolean operators || and &&  for boolean operations.

Answer (score 0):

Your OR in your WHERE will short your AND check.

Try for example the following which is equivalent to your logic:
`SELECT 'a' WHERE 1 = 1 OR 2 = 1 AND 3 = 1`

This will select `'a'`
What you're after is likely:

`select * from login where (username=@username or email = @email) and Password=@password"`

Answer (score 0):

You should consider grouping your condition in your query by parenthesizing them like

```
select * 
 from login 
 where (username=@username or email = @email) 
 and Password=@password";
```

Comment: I tried this query in mysql. This is my actual inputs (select * from login where (username='09840610866' or email = '09840610866') and Password='subhash123') but given empty result